# Prestashop: Set Category image as product image for products without pictures

Tags: image, prestashop, categories, product, prestashop-1.6

I have hundreds of products, most of them are without a product image. But I have images for categories, each category has its own image. IS IT possible to Set Category image as product image for products without pictures, in Prestashop ?

Comment: Yes it will be possible but with a script. Not in a few clicks.

Comment: "IS IT possible"... Rule nr. 1 in programming world - Nothing is impossible.

Comment: genuis comments -_- I know it should be done with a script, any idea how ?

Answer (score 0):

If you override the method getImageLink from Link class, you'll be able to check when this method returns the typical default image and change this to your needs. If you want something more performant, you would need a script to check directly on db these kind of products and generate images for them (using your category img), but you'll have to catch the case when you change your category image to update these.